# Android XML shape - Draw inward curves?

Tags: android, shapes, layer-list

I'm trying to create shapes that look like talk bubbles.
I've already created the bubble, but I'm trying to create the "tail" of the bubble in XML as well.

I had an idea that I could make ovals that hide an rectangle underneath them, but I doubt that it is possible.

How do I create this "tail" shape?

[image: Illustration]

This is just an ordinary triangle I've made:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="0%"
            android:pivotY="0%"
            >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle"
                >
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/white" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: simply use nine patch drawables, not (over) fancy xml stuff

Comment: @pskink Thank you for the quick response. What is the reason for the down vote?

Comment: i dont know, somebody found your question not so interesting...

Comment: Could you show us a picture of what you want to achieve ?